# Java Vert.x - Getting Result is already complete: succeeded Error

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient

I am trying to perform multiple database actions in my vertx code but for some reason I get this error

> Aug 18, 2021 12:20:09 PM io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
> SEVERE: Unhandled exception
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Result is already complete: succeeded
> at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.fail(FutureImpl.java:126)
> at com.himman.dao.ReturnRawmatToCompanyDAO.lambda$31(ReturnRawmatToCompanyDAO.java:801)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:327)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:366)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)

My code looks like so. Can someone please help.

```
public Future<String> delete(String id)
{
        Promise<String> deleted = Promise.promise();
        
        delete_1(id).onComplete(handler -> {
            delete_2(id).onComplete(handler_1 -> {
                delete_3_InvRaw_Mfg(handler_1.result()).onComplete(handler_2 -> {
                    delete_4_InvRaw_Company(handler_1.result()).onComplete(handler_3 -> {
                        deleted.complete(id);                       
                    });
                    
                });
            });
        });
        return deleted.future();
}
```

Comment: The exception is thrown when you try to fail a promise which was already completed or failed. It shouldn't happen with the code in the snippet above so I believe the actual code is actually more complex than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to complete a future/Promise which is already completed. From your code, I would suspect that it is the `deleted.complete(id);`.

Like pointed by @tsegismont, the code seems more complete than this.

From [doc](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Promise.html#complete--)

> Throws: IllegalStateException - when the promise is already completed